# Logging or Storage Ejabberd Sessions information

Tags: logging, xmpp, ejabberd

Is it possible to store information exchanged between users of an XMPP session with Ejabberd in a log file or in a database storage?

Ty

Answer (score 0):

mod_mam is included with ejabberd, and stores messages in Mnesia or ODBC database.

In the contributions repository there are other modules that maybe can be useful too, but probably they don't work with recent ejabberd versions:

- mod_log_chat logs chat mesages to text files
- mod_logxml logs all XMPP traffix to XML files